# read integer from file and save it into array

Tags: c

I have a file named plain.txt contain an integer for example 2500
I want to open this file and read the integer then compare it with another integer!!
here I want to compare the value of plain text with K.
how can I save the value of into another integer to compare??

```
int main(){
   int c,k=2000;
   FILE  *f;
   f=fopen("plain.txt", "r");
   c=getc(f);
   while(c!=EOF){
      putchar(c);
      c=getc(f);
   }
   fclose(f);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can use `fscanf()` to read into ineteger data using `%d` format specifier

Comment: What output do you get right now? Are you getting errors? Also, I recommend doing some searching around for basics. There are a lot of resources available.

Answer (score 1):

`getc()` reads characters. If file contains only integers you can do the following and get rid of the getc() calls.

```
int arr[100]; // Change the size accordingly or dynamically allocate.
int i=0;
    while(fscanf("%d", &c) == 1 ){
      arr[i]=c;
      i++;
    }
```

`i` will give the size of array at the end of loop and you can check the array for the integer.

Comment: Should be `== 1` in the `while`.

Comment: I want to use the integer out of while how can I save this value and using several times?

Comment: int c,i=0;
int s[100];
FILE  *f;
f=fopen("cipher.txt", "r");
while(fscanf("%d",&c)==1){
s[i]=c;
i++;
}
fclose(f);

I try this but tell me segmentation fault

Comment: @user1908123 check the return value of fopen if it was successful and make sure you have permission to read from the file.

Comment: when I put getc fopen return value succesful but when remove and out the code above the compiler output segmentation fault

Comment: I solved it: while(fscanf(f,"%d",&c)!=EOF){
s[i]=c;
printf("%d",s[i]);
i++;
}

Answer (score 0):

I know it is too late but I want to tell you that I also tried the first answer and got the wrong answer.The problem with above solution is that the fscanf() requires three arguments and you are providing only two arguments. The argument required is a file pointer f in your case.

```
int arr[100]; // Change the size accordingly or dynamically allocate.
int i=0;
    while(fscanf(f,"%d", &c) == 1 ){    //here was the issue
      arr[i]=c;
      i++;
    }
```